# How to reset Cisco 1721 router (can't get into rommon)

Tags: router

I've recently purchased a Cisco 1721 router and found out that it's protected by a password. I've tried to follow the standard [Cisco guide](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/routers/1700-series-modular-access-routers/22187-pswdrec-1700.html) to resolve the issue, but that didn't work. The guide assumes that I can type in some of the commands before the startup, but it's not true in my case (see the sreenshot)
[image]

While I'm trying to contact the person who sold me the item, I hoped to hear some of the suggestion as to how to approach the issue. Thank you.

UPD: so, to clarify, I need to get into the rommon mode, but I have no success in doing so although I follow the guide.

Comment: You typically use Break during boot (Break is available in Special Commands menu in Putty by clicking on the Icon in the top left corner of the Putty window) to put the Router in ROMMON mode so you can change the config register. The router should give you about 60 seconds to do this after power-on. That is outlined in the article you referenced at step 4.

Comment: @AtomicFireball Thank you, but it doesn't work no matter when I press the break button.

Comment: That's the only way to do it. I've had mixed luck with using the physical break key, so that's why I listed the Special Commands menu in Putty.

Comment: @PaulVergeev, have you tried other applications to connect to the serial port?  I've never had success getting into `rommon` using PuTTY, but I have with other communications programs.  (old TeraTerm on Windows, iirc, `screen`, at least one of `cu`, `tip`, `minicom` ...).

Comment: @user4556274 Just tried that out, but with no success. Apparently, the problem is that I use usb to com adapter. I can't get into the mode on any router I have.

Comment: @PaulVergeev, the obvious fallback is to use a machine with a DB-9 serial port.  I used to keep an old laptop with both a serial port and an RJ-11 (14?) modem port only to connect to old telecom devices which wouldn't work well with something like a usb-serial adaptor.  Sorry I don't have better suggestions; best of luck trying to find some workaround to get access to your 1721.

Answer (score 0):

Cisco maintains a [Password Recovery Procedures](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ios-nx-os-software/ios-software-releases-121-mainline/6130-index.html) web page that has links to instructions for specific devices, including 1700 series routers: [Password Recovery Procedure for the Cisco 1700 and 1800 Series Routers](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/routers/1700-series-modular-access-routers/22187-pswdrec-1700.html)

Comment: Sorry, but as I mentioned in the original post, I've reviewed the page. I can't get into ROMMON mode.

Comment: Then you are not doing it correctly. I have done this many times. Sometimes you need to try it over. As soon as you start seeing the bott process you need to start sending <BREAK>, over and over, until you get into ROMMON.

Comment: I'll keep on trying, but it's strange that I haven't had any sucess yet (I've tried 10 or more times). 
Also, the issue seems to be similar to that one: https://www.petri.com/forums/forum/networking/cisco-routers-switches-how-to/37142-cisco-1700-router-can-t-get-into-rommon

Comment: You need to make sure you are actually sending the <BREAK> signal on the serial line. You need to keep sending it until you get into ROMMON. A lot of people have trouble with this. See: https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/11390416/how-do-you-send-break-putty-cisco-2600-terminal-server